# Getting info from Twitch's API to check if a streamer is online for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py, twitch

I am trying to make a Discord bot to check if a streamer on Twitch is online when you type "$live" but I cannot get it to work. I'm using Discord.py. My main issue is using headers to call the API to supply my authorization. Also, with the code I currently have written, it sends this error. My main question is, How can I supply the authorization keys so that it doesn't either give the error below or say that OAuth is needed. TIA!

> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "main.py", line 19, in on_message
> response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 528, in request
> prep = self.prepare_request(req)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
> p.prepare(
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 317, in prepare
> self.prepare_headers(headers)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 449, in prepare_headers
> for header in headers.items():
> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Code below.

```
import discord 
import os
import requests

client = discord.Client()
url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels?query=whyoscar'
headers = {'client_id:' '*******************', 'Authorization:' 'Bearer **********************'}

@client.event
async def  on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  if message.content.startswith('$live'):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    details = response.json()
    await message.channel.send(details)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, you want to define your headers like so: `url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/search/channels?query=<channel you want to search for>&first=1' headers = {"client-id": os.getenv('CLIENT_ID_TOKEN'), "Authorization": os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN')}` then  put them in `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` , then get the response as JSON and check the response for `is_live=true`. That's all!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/invalid-oauth-token-on-channel/16110/5) on the Twitch forum, you will need a user token, not an application token.

The Twitch API documentation says

> OAuth or App Access Token required

...but it doesn't specify that the token needs to be a user token.

Anyway, go to [TwitchTokenGenerator](https://twitchtokengenerator.com/), select Bot Chat Token, login with your Twitch information and it should work.

Comment: Okay, I did that and fixed my formatting issues which gave me my original error, now it says "{'error': 'Unauthorized', 'status': 401, 'message': 'Client ID and OAuth token do not match'}" Why is that?

Comment: I also got that same error today. But earlier in the evening, everything worked fine. I'm not sure what the problem is, but your implementation seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OAuth to access Twitch API then the flow should be something along these line:

```
authURL = 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token'
client_ID = 'xxx'
secret = 'xxx'

AutParams = {'client_id': client_ID,
             'client_secret': secret,
             'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
             }

AutCall = requests.post(url=authURL, params=AutParams)
access_token = AutCall.json()['access_token']

head = {
    'Client-ID' : client_ID,
    'Authorization' :  "Bearer " + access_token
    }
```